# iOS : camera roll directory xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, camera-roll

I want to access camera roll directory  and want to look for some specific image.
I am new to xamarin, can you please guide me how to access camera roll directory

Comment: Did you want to getting the path of image that you select from the camera library?

Comment: what i did is i copy my image with help of phphotolibrary and now i just want to make sure that my image is copied to camera roll or not and for that i need path for camera roll

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1151/getting-the-name-of-pictures-taken-by-the-camera
here is description - you need to grant also privileges to Pictures folder

sample get path:
`var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);`

Comment: is this url is of camera roll of ios ?

Comment: URL is to similar question with other options than I provided (with path)

Comment: what i did is i copy my image with help of phphotolibrary and now i just want to make sure that my image is copied to camera roll or not and for that i need path for camera roll